# How to execute an external execution file with parameters in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to execute an exe file using Python 3.4.

That is,

```
C:/crf_test.exe -m input.txt output.txt
```

When I executed this at the command line, the result was:

```
Go SEARCH
to O
...
```

But, when I executed this in Python like this:

```
import os
os.startfile('crf_test.exe -m model.txt test.txt')
```

Nothing happened (I mean appeared in the result window.)

Answer (score 0):

Using os.popen() you can execute and read commands:

```
cmd = os.popen(r'crf_test.exe -m model.txt test.txt')
result = cmd.read()
```